# How to log events into Firebase Analytics from server side?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have a mobile application (Flutter) and an API (Python/Django). I use Firebase Analytics to track events in application side.

My server receives web hooks from ad service. I want to log event into Firebase Analytics when the server receive web hook.

How can I achieve this?

PS: There is a web hook to log event into Analytics, but not for the Firebase Analytics.

Comment: I dont think firebase analytics has an endpoint you can call to log data.

Comment: This is nowadays possible with https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1